# Does the Google Search Appliance have redundant power?

Tags: google-search-appliance, gsa

Are there redundant power supplies on the Google Search Appliance?

I believe that the GSA is essentially two 1u boxes pancaked together, so each of them would need a redundant power supply for the GSA to stay up during power loss from one UPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Google Search Appliance models GB-7007 and GB-9009 and the storage
>   unit for model GB-9009 are provided with two redundant power supplies.
>
> The Google Search Appliance model GB-1001 (series S5) is provided with
>   a single power supply, which can be augmented with a second,
>   user-installed power supply. The second power supply must be purchased
>   from Dell Computer. Copy the information from the Dell service tag on
>   the search appliance. Contact Dell to purchase the appropriate power
>   supply, which has the Dell part number 430-2240 / 430-2730. Installing
>   the power supply does not void the search appliance warranty.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/68/planning/planning#PowerSupply)

Comment: Good info, but please always link to the source when copy/pasting information from elsewhere.

Comment: confirmed ......